# Adding new line in the cursor position in QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to add new line in the given cursor position in QTextEdit.
I tried what's below.

Here new line is added to the end:

```
self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
self.textEdit.append()
```

This has no effects at all:

```
self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.PreviousWord)
self.textEdit.insertHtml('<br>')
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setHtml` or `insertHtml` with no actual content (text, resource, table, etc) will usually be ignored.

In this specific case, it's enough to add a blank space *before* or *after* the break:

```
    self.textEdit.insertHtml('<br/> ')
```

Using `append()` will not work for a given position of the cursor, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append):

> **Appends** a new paragraph with text to the **end** of the text edit.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>